# Next js 13 (app router) Caching is not working in home page { cache: 'no-store' }

Tags: reactjs, rest, next.js, fetch, next-auth

## Description of the Problem:

I am facing an issue with fetching data using the backendData function in my React application. When I fetch data one by one using the fetchData function, the data is successfully fetched. However, when I use the backendData function to fetch data for multiple categories simultaneously, I encounter an error.

## Expected Behavior:

I expect the code to fetch data for each category and render it in the MoviesCollection component.

## What I've Tried:

I have tried debugging the issue by logging the response data. The console output indicates that there is an error while fetching data for each category.

## Input Code

```
import React from "react";
import MoviesCollection from "../components/Movie_Collection";
const categoriesConfig = [
  { category: "contents", label: "Contents" },
  { category: "top_contents", label: "Top Contents" },
  { category: "content_movies", label: "Movies" },
  { category: "top_content_movies", label: "Top Movies" },
  { category: "content_seasons", label: "Web Series" },
  { category: "top_content_seasons", label: "Top Web Series" },
  { category: "content_adult", label: "18+ Contents" },
  { category: "top_content_adult", label: "Top 18+ Contents" },
];

export default async function Home() {
  const response = await backendData();
  const data = response.props.data;
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <main>
      {categoriesConfig.map((config, index) => (
        <MoviesCollection
          key={index + 1}
          data={data[config.category][0].data}
          collectionName={config.label}
          linkPath={`/data/${config.category}`}
        />
      ))}

    </main>
  );
}

async function fetchData(category, apiKey) {
  const response = await fetch(`${apiKey}/api/blogs/?category=${category}&page=1`, {cache: "no-store"});
  const data = await response.json();
  return { [category]: data };
}

export async function backendData() {
  const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
  const promises = categoriesConfig.map((config) => fetchData(config.category, apiKey));

  try {
    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
    const data = results.reduce((acc, result) => ({ ...acc, ...result }), {});
    return { props: { data } };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return { props: { data: {} } };
  }
}
```

Error Message:

```
{
  contents: { error: 'Error while fetching data' },
  top_contents: { error: 'Error while fetching data' },
  content_movies: { error: 'Error while fetching data' },
  top_content_movies: { error: 'Error while fetching data' },
  content_seasons: { error: 'Error while fetching data' },
  top_content_seasons: { error: 'Error while fetching data' },
  content_adult: { error: 'Error while fetching data' },
  top_content_adult: { error: 'Error while fetching data' }
}
 ⨯ app\page.js (24:41) @ data
    at eval (./app/page.js:54:48)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Home (./app/page.js:53:36)
  22 |         <MoviesCollection
  23 |           key={index + 1}
> 24 |           data={data[config.category][0].data}
     |                                         ^
  25 |           collectionName={config.label}
  26 |           linkPath={`/data/${config.category}`}
  27 |         />
```

## Context:

I am using Next.js, and the data fetching functions (fetchData and backendData) are part of my /app/page.js file. The application has individual API calls for each category, and I am using Promise.all to fetch data for all categories simultaneously.